# Is constant added to a normal distrubution, normal distributed?

Tags: normal-distribution

If $X$ is normal distributed, will $Z = c + X$, where c is any constant, also be normal distributed?

Comment: Yes indeed. Think that the distribution has the same shape graphically, just different axis labels.

Comment: Thanks. What you said about the graphical shape is a great point and makes sense when you calculate the mean of Z. You will get that it is the mean og X plus c, while the variance remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

If $F(x)$ is the CDF of $X$ then $G(x):=F(x-c)$ is the CDF of $X+c$. So one just shifts the CDF (or density) by $c$ units. To see this, notice that $G(x)=P(X+c\leq x)=P(X\leq x-c)=F(x-c).$